# Identify clusters of components that vary together

Tags: clustering, dataset

I have a number $M$ of populations. From each population, I sample $R$ vectors, where each vector has $N$ real components. The entire dataset consists of $M\times R\times N$ real numbers.

In this dataset I would like to identify groups of components (among the $N$ components) that exhibit similar variations among the $M$ populations, taking into consideration the level of statistical significance enabled by having $R$ replicas for each population.

Are there algorithms to do this?

Comment: Try to formalize your objective. What is formally a good solution?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Any pair of components within a cluster should have high correlation (Pearson, or a rank correlation) when compared against each other.